# encoding multipart mp4 files

Tags: ffmpeg

I am uploading a large mp4 files in chunks to the server. It is possible to encode these chunks using ffmpeg? and combine into a single file.

I tried this but getting moov atom not found/ Invalid data found when processing format.

However the first part of the chunk encodes correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not encode each chunk, because (surprise) the moov atom is missing. The moov atom is at the front (or sometimes back) of the file. Hence the first chunk encoding correctly. Without the moov, the rest of the file is gibberish. Other containers such as TS, or FLV are streamable, but even then you need complete GOPs to transcode each 'chunk'.

Comment: If I append the chunk to a files instead of write in different chunk. Is it possible to encode it?

Comment: Yes, if you reconstruct the file it will be decodable again